# How to write incremental data to hive using flink

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-flink

I use flink 1.6,I know I can use custom sink and hive jdbc to write to hive,or use JDBCAppendTableSink,but it is still use jdbc.The problem is hive jdbc do not suppot batchExecute method.I think it will be very slow.

Then I seek another way,I write a DataSet to hdfs with writeAsText method,then create hive table from hdfs.But there is still a problem:the how to append incremental data.
The api of WriteMode is:

```
Enum FileSystem.WriteMode
Enum Constant and Description
NO_OVERWRITE
Creates the target file only if no file exists at that path already.
OVERWRITE
Creates a new target file regardless of any existing files or directories.
```

For example,first batch,I write data of September to hive,then I get data of October,I want to append it.

But If I use  `OVERWRITE` to the same hdfs file,data of September will not exist any more,if I use `NO_OVERWRITE`,I must write it to a new hdfs file,then a new hive table,we need them in a same hive table.And I do not know how to combine 2 hdfs file to a hive table.

So How to write incremental data to hive using flink?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already wrote there is no HIVE-Sink. I guess the default pattern is to write (text, avro, parquett)-files to HDFS and define an external hive table on that directory. There it doesn't matter if you have a single file or mutiple files. But you most likely have to repair this table on a regular basis (`msck repair table <db_name>.<table_name>;`). This will update the meta-data and the new files will be available.

For bigger amounts of data I would recommend to partition the table and add the partitions on demand (This blogpost might give you a hint: https://resources.zaloni.com/blog/partitioning-in-hive).